# How to Buy Bitcoin without Taxes or Fees?

Tags: transactions, exchanges, transaction-fees

I'm looking for a solution to Buy Bitcoins without any Taxes or Fees is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is kind of an illogical question. I'll sell you a bitcoin for $10,000 with no taxes or fees. Is that what you want?

Comment: Taxes would be imposed by your country's government.  You haven't said which country that is, so we have no way of knowing whether you would be liable for any taxes on buying bitcoin, or if there are legal ways to avoid this.  We won't give you advice on how to illegally evade required taxes.

Answer (score 1):

You would avoid *exchange* fees if you bought directly from the seller without using an exchange, but the seller would still incur a miners' fee for validating the move from his/her address to your address (and would probably adjust his/her price accordingly). Taxes are a matter between you and your government (and perhaps the seller's government too if you're in different countries).